# Validation Rule for Radio buttons wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, radio-button, wpf-controls

I have a `RadioButton` inside `ItemsControl`. By default Radio Buttons will be unchecked. I want the user to select either of the radio buttons if a particular value (string value) is configured in another screen. I need to apply a validation rule for the same. If the user **does not** select either of the radio buttons, then on click on a submit button, I should display validation error.

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsUpdateSendDateConfigured}" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,2,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UpdateSendDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Width="400" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        <ItemsControl Name="updateSendDateLevelItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSendDateLevel}" Margin="10,5,0,10">
                 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton Height="25" GroupName="updateSendDateLevel" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Padding="10,0,10,0" >  <!--Need to apply Validation rule here -->
                                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                </RadioButton>
                         </DataTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

UpdateSendDateLevel is a view model which I am updating in the controller.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuredUpdateDueDateSelection))
{
       UpdateSendDateViewModel updateSendDateLevelViewModel = null;
       foreach (SendDate value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SendDate)).Cast<SendDate>())
       {
             updateSendDateLevelViewModel = new UpdateSendDateViewModel();
             updateSendDateLevelViewModel.UpdateSendDateLevel = value;
             updateSendDateLevelViewModel.Description = EnumHelper.GetDescription(value);

             m_sendDataContext.UpdateSendDateLevel.Add(updateSendDateLevelViewModel);
        }

}
```

Can someone please help with with adding xaml side validation rule or point me in the right direction?

Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: Why not bind button to ICommand and let CanExecute handle submit button enabled/disabled state instead of showing error afterwards?

Comment: Button has a lot of other fields to validate too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ValidationRules can be added as an extension of the Binding property, like so:

```
<RadioButton>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    <RadioButton.IsChecked>
        <Binding Path="Selected" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
          <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <rules:YourValidationRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
          </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </RadioButton.IsChecked>
</RadioButton>
```

(Note for the above that you don't actually need to use a TextBlock if all you're doing is putting text in the block. You can just include that text binding in the Content="" field on the RadioButton.)

Then you'd also need to define an object (YourValidationRule) that inherits from ValidationRule and overrides public ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo), and add a static reference (rules, in this case) to the namespace in which your custom ValidationRule exists.

An in-depth tutorial for ValidationRules exists on MSDN at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

However, Miiko is correct - it may be easier for you to use an object that implements ICommand, and use CanExecute to determine whether the customer may proceed. The main downside of this is that a ghosted, unusable button is not necessarily communicative, and you should be careful to ensure that your customers understand why they're unable to use the button.

Comment: True. You could show red exclamation mark or whatever after your control using validation rule, to visualize this is mandatory input in conjunction with ICommand implementation. For UX point of view, one can ask which is better a) let user click a button when-ever and show closable error message or give visual cues and enable button only when all selections are as they should be.

Comment: How do you add a Binding path for a radio button? I have done the extension for a text box but never for a radio button.

Comment: @MikkoViitala Yeah, I didn't mean to make it seem like I felt one way was the other. My personal preference is dialogs that tell the user exactly what they've neglected to do, but that's design-pattern-wise with MVVM.

Comment: @Vinay That depends entirely on what you're trying to bind. I'll flesh out the example above for the IsChecked property.

Comment: Thanks @furkle, it would be really helpful if you can give me an example for Radio button isChecked.

Comment: @furkle I did that before and there's nothing wrong with it. Now I prefer the above, providing tooltips or similar to give more info about what's wrong with user's selection/input.

Comment: @Vinay Hold up, I gotta actually try this out real quick - I think I might've miswritten something. Give me a minute.

Comment: @MikkoViitala and furkle, currently the application is showing a red exclamation mark in front of the fields which have errors with tool tips. But this is done using the validation rules. The Radio button is part of an enhancement and I would like to keep the same.

Comment: @Vinay Okay, the code above is syntactically correct. I'm not sure exactly sure what you mean. The red exclamation point is the way that WPF shows that fields are currently invalid, I'm pretty sure. What exactly is still wrong with the RadioButton?

Comment: I meant, currently for the other textbox fields,I am getting the red exclamation mark for the fields which are incorrect. But for Radio button I am not sure how to add a validation rule. Let me check with the updated code and get back to you.

Comment: The binding works and I still do not have a validation rule to go with. I will write a validation rule and it should do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I just made a quick update to move the binding from radio button into binding path. It is going to help other. I hope you don't mind.