# How bind validation to RadioButton WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have some problem with Radiobutton binding to show validation.

I create two `RadioButtons`

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,13,0,0">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding EndUser, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="End User" />
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding AppDeveloper, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="15,0,0,0" Content="App Developer"/>
</StackPanel>
```

for my logic I should take 1 name from 2.

I write the logic

```
[Required]
    public string Role
    {
        get => role;
        set
        {
            Set(ref role, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("EndUser");
            RaisePropertyChanged("AppDeveloper");
        }
    }

    public bool EndUser
    {
        get => Role.Contains("EndUser");
        set => Role = "EndUser";
    }

    public bool AppDeveloper
    {
        get => Role.Contains("AppDeveloper");
        set => Role = "AppDeveloper";
    }
```

the problem is how show `[Required]` in a form, and if i choose 1 of them, the validation will be true (validation work right if it's need i show the validation code)

I find this [Validation Rule for Radio buttons wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596373/validation-rule-for-radio-buttons-wpf) ,but this example doesn't work for me, broke all logic(doesn't send to me anything) and doesn't mark my field.

how write the

```
 <Binding.ValidationRules>
     <DataErrorValidationRule />
 </Binding.ValidationRules>
```

for radiobutton fields like in TextBox and mark it red?

my button  which disable if the fields is not valid

```
<Button x:Name="SignInButton" Command="{Binding SignInCommand}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Content="Sign In" >
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="10">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" Margin="24,5,24,4"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=Password}" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=Login}" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=Role}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF280895"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

in `MultiDataTrigger` i write the rule, if  Validation.HasError for the field the button is disable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example put a `Border` around the `RadioButtons` and use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `Role` property:

```
<Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Red" Margin="0,13,0,0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding EndUser, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="End User" />
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding AppDeveloper, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="15,0,0,0" Content="App Developer"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Role}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

You should then make the setter of the Role private and make sure to raise the PropertyChanged event for the involved properties:

```
private string role;
[Required]
public string Role
{
    get => role;
    private set
    {
        role = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Role");
    }
}

public bool EndUser
{
    get => Role == "EndUser";
    set
    {
        Role = "EndUser";
        RaisePropertyChanged("EndUser");
        RaisePropertyChanged("AppDeveloper");
    }
}

public bool AppDeveloper
{
    get => Role == "AppDeveloper";
    set
    {
        Role = "AppDeveloper";
        RaisePropertyChanged("AppDeveloper");
        RaisePropertyChanged("EndUser");
    }
}
```

Comment: it like decision, but 1. need to block button, code for button in MultiDataTrigger ` <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=Role}" Value="False"/>` isn't work button block for all the cases

2. it doesn't mark red radiobuttons

Comment: @Andrey: The RadioButtons are not marked. The Border is displayed when `Role == null`. I don't know where the `MultiDataTrigger` come from.

Comment: I edit my question and add the button xaml code with `MultiDataTrigger`

Comment: can you help to block the button if the Role == null, because if doesn't do that I can take null after click